# Displaying iPhone StopWatch like time in my own application ,should consists of minutes seconds and hundrerth seconds

Tags: iphone

i have to keep iphone type of stop watch on my app..if the user touches the start button in my app..

i already developed up to seconds. such like 00:01:45

and my problem is i have to get the hundredth second i.e like 01:014:48:95 ,if it crosses the 100 number the second will increase to 1

THanks in Adv...

Comment: At this level of detail, this question is impossible to answer. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a timer. If `1` == 1 second then `0.01` == 100th of a second.

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:0.01 ...`